# Peoplepicker not working in sharepoint 2019 lists

Tags: peoplepicker, sharepoint-2019

When I try to add a user, for example adding the user to the list column, it does not give auto-fill suggestions or resolve any user.

This SharePoint site was upgraded from SP2013.

Here is the console error:

Uncaught TypeError: a.set_allowOnlyEmailAddresses is not a function
at SPClientPeoplePicker.GetPeoplePickerQueryParameters (clientpeoplepicker.js?rev=xQZCUuvNj423eygeQ6yOJg%3D%3DTAG0:1:6764)
at SPClientPeoplePicker.AddPickerSearchQuery (clientpeoplepicker.js?rev=xQZCUuvNj423eygeQ6yOJg%3D%3DTAG0:1:5873)
at SPClientAutoFill.SPClientPeoplePicker_CallbackPopulateAutoFillFromEditor [as FuncPopulateAutoFill] (clientpeoplepicker.js?rev=xQZCUuvNj423eygeQ6yOJg%3D%3DTAG0:1:37590)
at autofill.js?rev=hRHNkHTVTVhEvdynOszVNg%3D%3DTAG0:1:10528
at arguments. (init.js?rev=9Z%2F3O15LXnsLkPxBBsfQFg%3D%3DTAG0:1:100002)

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here--assuming this is a programming issue.

Comment: If you are using existing software without any self-written code, please report this to the maintainers of that software